# When I type "code ." in wsl with ubuntu distro, it prompts something and asks me "y/N". How to remove that prompt?

Tags: command-line, rdp

I think this happened after I use RDP. Every time I write `code .` in the terminal it prompts:

```
To use Visual Studio Code with the Windows Subsystem for Linux, please install Visual Studio Code in Windows and uninstall the Linux version in WSL. You can then use the `code` command in a WSL terminal just as you would in a normal command prompt.
Do you want to continue anyway? [y/N] y
To no longer see this prompt, start Visual Studio Code with the environment variable DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL defined.
```

I tried uninstalling and installing VsCode but it didn't work. How can I stop seeing the prompt? How can I start VsCode with the environment variable `DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL`?

**EDIT:** None of the solutions below have worked but I removed and installed `code` and the `code .` works without the y/N prompt. But there is still the `DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL: command not found` at the top of the terminal.

[image: Prompt is still in wsl]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Henning [already explained](https://askubuntu.com/a/1418040/85695) how to set the variable manually, but another option is to make `code` an alias and set the variable there. Just add this line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias code='DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL=1 code'
```

This makes the command `code` actually run `DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL=1 code` which means it will be running with the variable set. Note that you need to open a new terminal so `.bashrc` is read, or manually source the file (`. ~/.bashrc`) for the changes to take effect.

Comment: your's and henning's didn't work. I got the `code .` command to work now without the y/N prompt but there is still the `DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL: command not found` at the top of the terminal.

Comment: @jared-dev what did you do though? This will work if you do it exactly as described, but the error you mention means you probably have a lone `DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL` somewhere in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: nvm it worked now when I typed the command in bashrc file in vscode

Answer (score 2):

Please note the actual meaning of the text, it recommends using the windows version of some **obscure** reason (i.e. don't have it installed in WSL/Ubuntu).

Open a bash shell and type this after the `$` prompt

```
$ echo >>"$HOME/.bashrc" "DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL=No_Prompt_please"
```

Close that shell, start a new... then try `code`

**More info on bash usage:**

- man bash
- [www.tldp.org](http://www.tldp.org) -> Bash guides (there are two, lengthy, many examples)

Comment: I tried it on git bash, Powershell, and cmd but it didn't work. In git bash and PowerShell nothing happens after typing it. In cmd, it said, "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: and when I opened wsl, at the top it said `DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL: command not found`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `export DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL=No_Prompt_please` Also, you can source bashrc so you don't need to log out to apply the changes: `source ~/.bashrc` or `. ~/.bashrc`

Comment: This is assuming BASH and BASH only, cmd.exe and powershell belongs in windows, and there only IMO. I have change minuscule details above, use any editor that uses LF as linefeed character and edit .bashrc; e.g. `nano .bashrc` at the bash prompt.

Comment: @mchid export is to make it available globally, not necessary if you run a SINGLE bash shell; and this is especially true as it resides in .bashrc which gets executed for every bash invocation, unless you do special things.

Comment: One more thing: with two OS'es (or more), for the least amount of problems and issues; keep them as separate as possible, i.e. only sharing files, converting linefeed modes if necessary (sudo apt install dos2unix; man dos2unix, https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix ).

Comment: `set` is not used to set variables in bourne-family shells like bash, it is used to set shell option (e.g. `set -x`). Adding the line in your answer will have no effect in bash since `DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL=No_Prompt_please` is not a valid shell option.

Comment: `set` removed, misconception from my side. There was a SPACE before `=` initially, which was the true problem.

Comment: @terdon `$ DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL=No_Prompt_please` -> `$ echo $DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL` --- produces ---> `No_Prompt_please` - Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Yes, of course it does. But `set DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL=No_Prompt_please` and then `echo $DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL` will print nothing, and your answer is suggesting using `set`, which is wrong in this context. The C-shell family of shells, `tcsh` for instance, use `set` for defining variables, perhaps you're thinking of those? Ah, I see you removed it, yes this should now work. However, `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` would be better choices for this sort of setting since it doesn't need to be reapplied on each new shell. But still, `.bashrc` will work.

Comment: As I write above, `set`has been removed. I have probably read e.g. tcsh docs some time and not noted it being that.

Comment: Both `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile` *( ~ evaluates to $HOME when used at the prompt, but only there )* are both a better choice, yes; those are present in `man bash`and in the referenced bash guides. I laid the brickwork for Education time now get going... **Notable:** I have at least a couple of decades of bash-hacking experience (can't remember when I did my first things), errors still appear!

Comment: @Hannu ha! I have at least a couple of decades experience also, and the day errors stop appearing will be the day I stop coding :)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I start VsCode with the environment variable DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL?

From what I understand, vscode will check whether this environment variable is definied. So you need to set `DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL` to an arbitray value.

You can set an environment variable in several ways. For example, you can precede it to a command like this

```
LANG=fr_FR somecommand
```

In your case, this would be something like

```
DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL=whatever code
```

With this method, the environment variable is only defined for this specific call, so you'd need to set it every time you start vscode.

Another way is to `export` the environment variable into your shell. So you could do something like

```
export DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL=whatever
code
```

With this method, the enviroment variable is defined for the remainder of the shell session, so you'd need to set it every time you open a new shell session. Within a shell session where you've `export`ed the environment variable once, you don't need to export it again (unless you want the change the environment variable, obviously).

There are also some configuration files that can be used to set environment variables. `.bashrc` (note the dot in front) in your home directory has already been mentioned in another answer, another one would be `.pam_environment` also in your home directory. I'm not really familiar with the perculiarities of WSL, so I won't go into details here.

Comment: Note that you don't need to `export` it, that is only needed if you require the variable to also be set in any child shells. In this case, `DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL=whatever` is enough without the `export`.

Comment: didn't work. nothing happened after doing those.