# How to Compile and Run [package] with Cflags Program on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: environment-variables

dear community!
I am going to install ringserver.
instruction tells: after downloading and installing (using 'make' command on terminal) "Compiler options can be tuned by setting the CFLAGS environment variable".
would you please , how to use GFLAGS env. in ubuntu terminal?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418035/when-i-type-code-in-wsl-with-ubuntu-distro-it-prompts-something-and-asks-me/1418040#1418040) to another question solve your problem? In that case, environment variables were used for a different purpose, but your question seems to be about how to set environment variables in general.

Comment: it gives nothing....unfortunately...

Comment: @nqnr please [edit] your question to clarify the problem - do you not understand how to set environment variables? or is your question about how to use the `CFLAGS` variable specifically? What exactly do you think needs to be "tuned", and why?

Comment: question is about how to use the CFLAGS variable specifically?